# How can I backup the ACLs of an ADLS GEN1?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I need to make a backup of all the Access Control Lists that have all the folders of my ADLS GEN1(Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1. I've been looking and I can't find anything.
Do any of you have any experience or idea of how you could do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot backup the ACLs and privileges of Azure Data Lake Gen1 store.

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34048126-copy-acl-and-privileges-in-data-lake-store

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.